# How to prevent file uploads to the Internet from within the LAN

Tags: squid, network-monitoring

We use a [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29) proxy server for outbound requests to the Internet. We would like to prevent any kind of file uploads to a website in the Internet (for example, [RapidShare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RapidShare) ...). How do we achieve this? We have the Squid proxy server running on the Windows 2003 domain controller machine, and we have less than 10 machines.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this a security issue or are you trying to conserve bandwidth?

Comment: its a security issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Upstream can't be banned as this is required.
Use Blacklist to ban such sites.

Comment: ok - your suggestion to keep black listing the sites until you are comfortable. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Given most file upload services use common and useful protocols such as HTTP/HTTPS over 80/443 it probably makes more sense to block the unwanted domains via your proxy rather than by protocol.